# find out if url is compressed

Tags: php

I just have a question thats been pozzling my head all morning.

I want to get all http headers thru CURL ... and find out, if pinged url is compressed, or not. (either one of: gzip / x-gzip / deflate / compress)

But all I can get from CURL is this:

```
[url] => http://www.url
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 302
[header_size] => 764
[request_size] => 54
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.042535
[namelookup_time] => 0.002779
[connect_time] => 0.014986
[pretransfer_time] => 0.015039
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 218
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.042204
[redirect_time] => 0`
```

Nothnig like "Content-encoding" ... any chance to get that thru PHP?

Comment: Did you try sending `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip`

Comment: Why do you need this? Usually curl should decode it for you, so usually there is no reason to take care of it.

Comment: Need to test, if given link returns compressed / gzipped header :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the headers from curl and parse them for the `Content-Encoding` header.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://stackoverflow.com/");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$header_size = $curl_info["header_size"];
$headers = substr($buffer, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($buffer, $header_size);


function getEncoding(&$headers){
    $arr=explode("\r\n",trim($headers));
    array_shift($arr);
    foreach($arr as $header){
        list($k,$v)=explode(':',$header);
        if ('content-encoding'==strtolower($k)){
            return trim($v);
        }
    }
    return false;
}   

$encoding=getEncoding($headers);

if ($encoding) {
    echo "Using: ".$encoding;
}else{
    echo "None";
}

?>
```

Comment: Altho, for somo reasson, it throws error with google.com for example.. ./ hm

Comment: Not error - in a way of PHP error, but it says google.com is not gzipped - but it is. Must be the redirects googles using. Try the script with google.com, or youtube.com

Comment: the redirect itself is not compressed. To get a compressed response from google, you would have to fake the user-agent header. I added `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0` this to the headers (as second element in the array) and i got a compressed response. (for the redirect target not the redirect itself)

Comment: Cheers for that, I actually found and combined fucntion that find the redirects url first, and gives it back ... and if its not redirected, just gives back one provided ... that way, it works 100% times! Thanks for your help Steve, you've been great help! Apprciated!